# Error when binding gridview data to a datatable

Tags: c#

I've a gridview in which i bind some data to it.After binding it i want to get the gridview content in a new data table.

Here's my c# code

```
    Datatable dt_NewTable = new DataTable();        
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gdMainDetails.Rows)
    {            
        DataRow dr = dt_NewTable.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < gvRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = gvRow.Cells[i].Text;
        }
        dt_NewTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

The problem is that i'm getting 'gvRow.Cells[i].Text' as "".
What's the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

gridView Cell is a container...you must have to pull out the control from it and than get its text..like

Label lblControl = (Label)gvRow.Cells[i].FindControl("controlID");
dr[i] = lblControl .text;

And by the way you also have to define the column(s) of Your DataTable first..!!!
i.e structure of the Datatable should be same as your grid wants..!!